# 301 redirect both www and non-www to fake directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want my site to always redirect to a default language if one is not already requested by the user — i.e. if the default language is English, I want to redirect the user to **http://domain.com/english/** when he/she enters **http://domain.com/**.

At the same time, I want to remove the 'www' part from the URL, as well as redirect all traffic through **http://domain.com/index.php**.

I have the following .htaccess file, which is working great when the user enters **www.domain.com**, but not when the user enters **domain.com** (without 'www'). What am I doing wrong?

```
#
# Remove WWW from URL
#

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/english/$1 [R=301,L]

#
# Redirect all traffic through index.php
#

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Remove WWW from URL and redirect to /english/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/english/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
```

With `?` to make the www optional so the first rule catches both.

**Edit:**

Use this rule to remove the www., then use a redirect on the index.php page to go to /english/ instead of a url rewriting rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am getting a "The page isn't redirecting properly" from Firefox :/

Comment: @josocblaugrana: Indeed.  My rule would make it constantly redirect, now that I think about it.

Comment: How can I redirect on the index.php in a SEO friendly manner?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/english/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You're saying if the host is not exactly www.example.com, then redirect to it.

Comment: Sorry, no go. With this, 'www' does not redirect at all, and without 'www' I am getting a redirection error from Firefox.

Comment: Still no go, I am afraid :/ This does not remove 'www' from the url.

Comment: ... would help if I had read your post correctly. :-) Try it the way I have it now

Comment: Now example.com (without 'www') does not redirect.